# Charm++ Build options not supported

Tags: charm++

I am working on the parallel programming language - Charm++. I have installed it's framework on my System: Ubuntu 14.04, 32bit. But when I started the build option to initiate the Charm++ environment, I am getting these errors. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve these errors ?

user@user-HCL-ME-Laptop:~/Documents/charm-6.7.1$ ./build charm++ multicore-linux   -j4
Error> option: linux is not supported in this version!
Supported compilers: clang craycc gcc gcc3 icc icc8 iccstatic pgcc xlc xlc64
Supported options: bigemulator bigsim g95 gfortran ifort lcs ooc papi persistent pgf90 tsan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the 32-bit Linux multicore build is named 'multicore-linux32' rather than 'multicore-linux' (though the 32-bit Linux net build is 'netlrts-linux'). The inconsistency in naming of build targets like this has now been fixed in the development branch of Charm++ and will be shipped in the upcoming 6.8.0 release. Thanks for pointing it out!